# Error Page not found (404) Request Method: GET in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-class-based-views

Good afternoon:
I see this error of Django when I try to update a "Usuario":

```
Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/usuarios/modificar/
Using the URLconf defined in COMBOOK.urls, Django tried these URL patterns in this order:
^ ^$ [name='login']
^ ^cerrar/$ [name='logout']
^ ^registrarse/$ [name='registrarse']
^autor/
^libros/
^usuarios/ ^registrar/$ [name='registrar_usuario']
^usuarios/ ^reportar/$ [name='reportar_usuario']
^usuarios/ ^modificar/(?P<email>\d+)/$ [name='modificar-usuario']
^tipos_usuario/
^admin/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, usuarios/modificar/, didn't match any of these.
```

This file is models.py

```
from django.db import models
from apps.tipos_usuario.models import Tipo_Usuario


class Usuario(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 80, verbose_name = 'Email', unique = True)
    contrasena = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name = 'Contrasena')
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length = 80, verbose_name = 'Nombres')
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length = 80, verbose_name = 'Apellidos')

    opciones_genero = (
        ('F', 'F',),
        ('M', 'M',),
    )

    genero = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = opciones_genero)

    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Fecha de Nacimiento")

    tipo_usuario = models.ForeignKey(Tipo_Usuario, verbose_name = 'Tipo Usuario')

    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.email

    def get_email(self):
        return self.email
```

This one is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from .views import RegistrarUsuario, ReportarUsuario, ModificarUsuario


urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^registrar/$' , RegistrarUsuario.as_view() , name="registrar_usuario"),
    url(r'^reportar/$' , ReportarUsuario.as_view() , name="reportar_usuario"),

    url(r'^modificar/(?P<email>\d+)/$', ModificarUsuario.as_view(),name='modificar-usuario'),

)
```

This one is views.py

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView,TemplateView,ListView, UpdateView

from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin  # handles authentication
from .models import Usuario
from apps.usuarios.models import Usuario
from apps.tipos_usuario.models import Tipo_Usuario
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage
from django.core.paginator import PageNotAnInteger


class RegistrarUsuario(CreateView):
    template_name = 'usuarios/registrarUsuario.html'
    model = Usuario
    success_url = reverse_lazy('reportar_usuario')


class ReportarUsuario(ListView):
    template_name = 'usuarios/reportarUsuarios.html'
    model = Usuario
    context_object_name = 'usuarios'
    paginate_by = 2


class ModificarUsuario(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'usuarios/modificarUsuario.html'
    model = Usuario
    success_url = reverse_lazy('modificar-usuario')

    def get_object(self):
        return Usuario.objects.get(email=self.request.GET.get('email'))
```

This one is modificarUsuario.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Modificar Usuario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Modificar Usuario</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for usuario in usuarios %}
            <li class="contact">{{ usuario }}
                (<a href="{% url "modificar-usuario" pk=email %}">Editar</a>)
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

And I have a file named "base.html" where I try to call the html file "modificarUsuario.html" inside a option in a class=nav:

```
<li><a href="/usuarios/modificar/">Modificar Usuario</a></li>
```

Could someone explain me how could I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says, there is no URL that matches just /usuarios/modificar/. Your modification view expects a third segment, which is an integer (which you've called email, for some reason).

You've defined the link correctly once, inside modificarUsuario.html, where you use the `{% url %}` tag to construct it. But in the base template you have just linked to /usarios/modificar/, which doesn't exist; you should use the same structure there to link to a specific user's modification page.

(Actually there are a large number of other things wrong with this code, but that will do for starters.)